# AWS: Using CloudFront as CDN for non-AWS hosted content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way (say by providing a Route53 endpoint as origin) to distribute non-AWS hosted content using CloudFront?

(assuming the Route53 is used as dns for a site hosted outside of amazon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront doesn't care where your origin server is hosted or even who you use for DNS.  As long as the [Origin Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName) you provide is resolvable from the Internet (and has valid SSL configuration, if enabled), CloudFront will fetch the content from that origin the same as it will fetch it from anywhere inside AWS.